# How is a question about Windows Defender not restoring a quarantined file off topic?

Tags: discussion

How is this off topic? Windows defender restore quarantined file not working.

The closed reason links to "What topics can I ask about here" which doesn't clarify what is wrong at all so I can't edit it to make it on topic. No comments on how to fix it. Nothing in the help doc tells me what is wrong with the post so odds are it will happen again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "security tools" inclusion is usually for questions about how security is performed by a tool, or why a tool included a feature and how it relates to the security of that tool. It's a gray line, but we try to keep away from Support level questions.

Your question is probably better suited for Microsoft support or SuperUser StackExchange where there are experienced individuals in diagnosing what went wrong with an enterprise level software.

Comment: Thank, you! That was much more helpful than "because I said so".
I'd recommend clarifying the "what topics can I ask about here" doc.
It might be clear to people that are using it to enforce rules and that like to hit people with it and not provide any other context when someone asking for help does something that follows the document but is actually "wrong" when all the unwritten rules are taken into account. 
Gray lines are always hard to nail down but there is a lot of room for improvement with that document from the point of view of the intended consumer of it.

Answer (score 0):

It just isn't a security question as per our site scope. It's a computing question. Might be on topic over on Super User.

Just because Defender is a security doesn't make the question about it on topic.

Comment: So in the examples when it specifically says that "security tools " are on topic. What can you ask about them if not using them? I mean "Antivirus" is a tag there too. Should antivirus be listed in the off topic document?